# Нужна помощь с ArrayList в javafx!

Tags: массивы, javafx, intellij-idea, arraylist, scene-builder

Вообщем проблема такая: мне нужно сделать `ArrayList`, в котором будут храниться `TextField`-ы далее присвоить каждому из них `TextFormatter`. Я написал код:

```
@FXML
    private void handleChanger(javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent event) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".{0,1}");
        TextFormatter formatter = new TextFormatter<>(change -> {
            change.setText(change.getText().toUpperCase());
            return pattern.matcher(change.getControlNewText()).matches() ? change : null;
        });
        ArrayList<TextField> textFields = new ArrayList<>();
        textFields.add(TF_7_3);
        textFields.add(TF_7_4);
        textFields.add(TF_7_5);
        textFields.add(TF_7_6);
        textFields.add(TF_7_7);
        for (TextField tf : textFields){
            if(event.getSource() == tf);
        }
        textFields.forEach(textField -> {
            textField.setTextFormatter(formatter);
        });
```

, но когда я вписываю, что либо в `TextField` вылазит эта ошибка:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1787)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1670)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.process(Scene.java:4098)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processKeyEvent(Scene.java:2157)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.keyEvent(Scene.java:2625)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:217)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:149)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleKeyEvent$1(GlassViewEventHandler.java:248)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:412)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleKeyEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:247)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleKeyEvent(View.java:547)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyKey(View.java:971)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:76)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:273)
    at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:83)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1782)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Formatter is already used in other control
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.TextFormatter.bindToControl(TextFormatter.java:192)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl$5.invalidated(TextInputControl.java:319)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:112)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:147)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl.setTextFormatter(TextInputControl.java:342)
    at sample.ScanwordController.lambda$handleChanger$1(ScanwordController.java:450)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1510)
    at sample.ScanwordController.handleChanger(ScanwordController.java:449)
    ... 41 more
```

При всём этом `TextFormatter` присваивается только в первый `TextField`,тобишь в тот который я первым записал символ, а второй и последующие в которые я впишу что-нибудь, без него.

Comment: Как говорят на [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/JavaFX/comments/gp7wyp/comment/frpqzkh) используйте [разные `TextFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.html). См. последнюю ошибку (`java.lang.IllegalStateException`)

Comment: @ВасяВоронцов  , Я никак не могу реализовать метод `clone()` в `TextFormatter` , перепробовал кучу способов, но всё время выходит не так как надо [https://imgur.com/a/NDkijQr](https://imgur.com/a/NDkijQr) , может подскажите что-то ?